# Mock objects not working with CXF WebClient.create().post()

Tags: java, rest, mockito, cxf

I'm trying to write a unit test for web service calls. Using Mockito to mock DAO layer. Problem I'm facing is that when WebClient's `post()` is called, then mocked objects become null. Request is loaded in different context. Following is the code snippet:

```
    @Before
    public void doSetup() {
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    sf.setResourceClasses(UserService.class);
    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    providers.add(new JacksonJsonProvider());
    sf.setProviders(providers);
    sf.setResourceProvider(UserService.class, 
            new SingletonResourceProvider(new UserService(),true));
    sf.setAddress(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);
    Server server = sf.create();

    mockDelegator = Mockito.mock(UserDelegator.class);
    mockUserDao = Mockito.mock(UserDAO.class);
    mockDelegator.setUserDao(userDao);
    userService.setUserDelegator(mockDelegator);
    }

    @Test    
    public void fetchPersonalInformationTest() {
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);
    WebClient.getConfig(client).getRequestContext().put(LocalConduit.DIRECT_DISPATCH, Boolean.TRUE);
    client.path("users/fetchPersonalInfo");
    client.accept("application/json");
    client.type("application/json");
    Response response = client.post("{\"userName\":\"vijay@1357\"}"); //This call's UserService and thows NullPointerException for userDao and mockDelegator
    }
```

Following snippet is from the UserService class:

```
@POST
@Path("/fetchPersonalInfo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response fetchPersonalInformation(User user) {
    logger.error("Logger Running");
    String fetchJsonPersonalInfo=null;
    System.out.println(user.getUserName());
    try {
        BasicUtils.isNull(user.getUserName());
        BasicUtils.isNull(userDelegator);
        fetchJsonPersonalInfo = userDelegator.fetchPersonalInformation(user);
    } catch (ApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(fetchJsonPersonalInfo).build();
}
```

UserDelegator class

```
public String fetchPersonalInformation(User user) {
    BasicUtils.isNull(userDao);
    return userDao.fetchPersonalInformation(user);
}
```

UserDAO clas

```
public String fetchPersonalInformation(User user) {
    logger.info("Started Execution at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    String json=null;
    try {
        Statement query = QueryBuilder.select().json().from("members_data", "users").where(QueryBuilder.eq("username",user.getUserName()));
        ResultSet resultset = executeStatementOrQuery(query);
        Row row = resultset.one();
        json = row.getString("[json]");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ApplicationException(Constants.ERROR_CODE_101, errMsg101, e);
    }
    logger.info("Finished Execution at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    return json;
}
```

Comment: The call `mockDelegator.setUserDao(userDao);` won't do anything, since `mockDelegator` is a mock.  You could try `return(userDao).when(mockDelegator).getUserDao();` instead.  But you haven't shown enough of your code for me to be sure that will work for you.

Comment: I just added almost complete code. `UserDelegator` doesn't have `getUserDao()` but on debugging I can see that on `client.post()` call `mockDelegator` is also null

Comment: `when(WebClient.create(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS)).thenReturn(mockWebClient);` and `when(mockWebClient.post(any(String.class)).thenReturn("Some string");` That should get you started. You could also return an actual `WebClient` object if you don't want to mock it. Be careful mocking, as when you mock you loose the ability to test that part.

Comment: Umm, in my earlier comment I obviously meant `doReturn`, not `return`.  Typing a bit too quickly there.

Comment: And there's still not nearly enough code here to work out what's going on.  You should probably show us the classes that you're actually testing, not just the test class.  Otherwise, we're all just guessing.  I'm going to VTC this because it's not an MVCE yet.

Comment: @DavidWallace, added more code. Kindly check

Comment: OK, an MVCE is something that I can actually run, on my own computer, to work out what's going  wrong.  I can't run your program if you only give me half of it.

Comment: @Chewtoy, Mocking Webclient works however, it seems to defeat the purpose of CXF Local Transport.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWallace and @ Chewtoy for your time on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Issue was in setting resource class for `JAXRSServerFactoryBean`. Changed the following code from:

```
@Before
public void doSetup() {
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setResourceClasses(UserService.class);
```

chagned to

```
@Before
public void doSetup() {
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setServiceBean(userService);
```

> If you prefer not to let the JAX-RS runtime handle the resource class lifecycle for you (for example, it might be the case that your resource class is created by other containers such as Spring)

Reference document [CXF JAX-RS Service Configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-ConfiguringJAX-RSservicesprogrammatically)